# Что не так в двоичном поиске? На отладке сразу вылетает

Tags: c++, алгоритм, search, двоичный-поиск

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int _bsearch(std::vector<int> n, int element, int low, int hight){

      int mid = n.size()/2;
      if(element == n[mid])
        return mid;

      if(element < n[mid]){
          return _bsearch(n, element, low, mid - 1);
        }
      else if (element > n[mid]) {
          return _bsearch(n, element, mid + 1, hight);
        }
}
 int main(){

  std::vector<int> v = {1,2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10};
  std::cout << _bsearch(v, 7, 0, v.size() - 1);

}
```

Comment: В двоичном поиске всё так, а вот в вашем коде...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, стоит

```
int mid = n.size()/2;
```

заменить на что-то типа

```
int mid = (high + low)/2;
```

?

У вас `mid` **всегда** одно и то же...

Comment: ой, точно, спасибо!

Comment: не отладывается все равно чет

Comment: Написать за вас полностью?

Comment: нет, получилось, там у вас нужно (hight + low)/2

Comment: Да, конечно, очепятался. Спасибо.